# Get last day of month - returning a couple days off

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell (`W3`) with `February` in the cell.  I would like to find the last day of February with a formula.

I have tried this formula: `=DATE(2016,MONTH(1&W$3),EOMONTH(MONTH(1&W$3),0))`

However, it returns `3/2/2016`, instead of `2/29/2016`, how come? If I have `December` as the text, it correctly returns `12/31/2016`.  November does the same error, if I have `November`, then it's returning `12/1/2016`.

I think it's with how I'm using the `Month()`? But I'm not sure why it's acting oddly.  Thanks for any tips!

Comment: the adding 1 to the front of your month as a text seems weird to me.  not saying its wrong, just weird....but hey it works

Comment: @ForwardEd The [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314ffa1-2bc9-4005-9d66-f49db127d628) states entering the `start_date` argument of `EOMONTH` as text can cause problems.  It's supposed to be a `DATE` value.

Comment: `=EOMONTH(DATE(2016,MONTH(W3),DAY(W3)),0)`

Comment: or `=EOMONTH(DATE(2016,MONTH("1 "&W3),1),0)`

Comment: @BruceWayne So in light of Darren's answer, your formula was working just fine for all months with 31 days in them! 8)

Comment: @ScottCraner  I prefer the second formula,  Why bother calculating the day when you can hard code it as 1 since 1 is in all months and is not going to really get used in the end.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah, thanks! That works excellently (the second).  I'll technically be using that as my "answer", since I need to change the year.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work: `=EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("1 " & W3),0)`

That gives the end of month value - not sure why your formula doesn't though.
`=MONTH(1&W$3)` correctly returns 2....
actually that would turn your EOMONTH formula into `=EOMONTH(2,0)` which returns 31 which is 2nd March if there's 29 days in February.

The 2 should be a date rather than number - so date is converted to 02/01/1900.

Comment: dang it, I reloaded your edit and you just beat me to what I was going to say

Comment: FWIW this will always use the current year.  If that is what is wanted then this is the best way. ++

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! Since I'll need the year to be changeable (sorry, didn't make that note in my OP), I'll use this for those with the current year.  Marked as Answer, since your explanation explained it and it works. :D

Comment: Sorry the explanation was a bit rushed - was 5:30 Friday evening and didn't see the reason at first.